# Convert minute to time for display

Tags: javascript, beginner, datetime, formatting

I am new to javaScript, I just coded a method where I can convert a minute to a time in hh:mm AP/PM. I was then displaying the time in a table.  I was wondering if there is a better approach to this? Because my code seems quite messy, with many `if` and `else` statement.

```
function convertMinsToHrsMin(minutes) {
                var str = '';
                var h = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
                var m = minutes - (h * 60);
                h = h < 10 ? '0' + h : h;
                m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m;
                if (h >= 12) {
                    if (h == 12) {
                        str = "PM";
                    }
                    else if (h >= 22) {
                        h = (h - 12);
                        str = "PM";
                    }
                    else {
                        h = '0' + (h - 12);
                        str = "PM";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (h == 0) {
                        h = 12;
                        str = "AM";
                    }
                    else {
                        str = "AM";
                    }                     
                }                          
                return h + ":" + m + " " + str;
            }

            startTime = convertMinsToHrsMin(720);
            endTime = convertMinsToHrsMin(1080); 

            alert(startTime);
            alert(endTime);
```

Here is a jsFiddle to work on: https://jsfiddle.net/Issaki1/txns3mhc/

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering if there is a better approach to this?

Yes. [Use a library](https://momentjs.com/). Using what's already done is always better than doing it yourself. ;)

The next best thing you could do is convert minutes into milliseconds and instantiate a `Date` object from it. From there, JS does most of the heavy lifting for you. Here's an example (not extensively tested, but you get the idea):

```js
const pad = n => `0${n}`.slice(-2)

const convertMinsToHrsMin = mins => {
  const date = new Date(mins * 60 * 1000)
  
  // Need to be UTC since timestamps are universal
  // but normal time methods operate based on local time.
  const hours = date.getUTCHours()
  const minutes = date.getUTCMinutes()
  
  // If 0, as in 00:00 or 12:00, default to 12.
  const hours12 = hours % 12 || 12
  const period = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'
  
  return `${pad(hours12)}:${pad(minutes)}${period}`
}

startTime = convertMinsToHrsMin(720);
endTime = convertMinsToHrsMin(1080);

alert(startTime);
alert(endTime);
```

As for your code:

- Use `console.log` instead of `alert`. I know `alert` is a quick way to visualize values, but getting the habit of using `console.log` will do wonders for your skin.
- Avoid very deep and branchy conditionals. `if` statements don't do anything on its own and has to be mutating some variable. That means you define variables up top. There is a chance that you might miss a branch and leave that variable empty or contain an unwanted value.
- Use a ternary for short conditionals, like determining AM and PM. It's short, and gets you into not mutating variables.
- Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to construct strings. This way, you don't need to break out strings and you always get a string (not a `NaN` should your expression fail you due to coercion).
- And lastly, get familiar with the native APIs. They do lots of heavy lifting for you so you don't have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code simplified. A few points:

- I am very skeptical on whether should you use a library for a ten
  lines function. But you should first check what js native has to
  offer before go your own way. Check around `Date` object and see what
  you find.
- Do not mess numbers with strings and in general, do not
  mix data types even if the language allows that. That is why I use
  `h_literal` to form the string

  ```
  function convertMinsToHrsMin (minutes) {
   var meridiem = 'PM', 
    h = Math.floor (minutes / 60),
    m = minutes - (h * 60),        
    m_literal = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m,
    h_literal 
   ;
  if (h == 0) {
    h = 12;
    meridiem = "AM";
  }
  else if (h > 12) {
    h -= 12;
  } 
  else if (h != 12) {
    meridiem = "AM";
  }  
  h_literal = h < 10 ? '0' + h : h;                            
    return h_literal + ":" + m_literal + " " + meridiem;
  }    
  startTime = convertMinsToHrsMin(720);
  endTime = convertMinsToHrsMin(1080); 
  console.log(startTime);
  console.log(endTime);
  ```